# Why can I not get the name of my JButton in a mouseEntered method?

Tags: java

I have a button on a form that I want to detect if the mouse is over the button. If the button is over the form I want to flash a JLabel that has  completely red background color to indicate stop or warning or something along that lines.

The e.getComponent() returns the calling component, so in this case is should be the Save Jbutton. But the name is null?

When I have the name I check if source.equals(myButton) which then should put the label on the JFrame

Code:

```
    @Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    final Component source = e.getComponent();
            final JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(source);

    System.out.println("entered:" + source.getName());

    if (source.equals("btnSave")) {
       System.out.println("save button");
        JLabel StopLabel = new JLabel("test");
                StopLabel.setOpaque(true); 
        StopLabel.setEnabled(true);
        StopLabel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        StopLabel.setBounds(10, 203, 150, 23);
                frame.add(StopLabel);
            }

}
```

Comment: When do you set the name of your JButton? What happens if you print out the value returned from the JButton's getName() method directly?

Answer (score 1):

`getName()` isn't the label of the button, you need to call `getText()` instead.
e.g.

```
    JButton randomButton = new JButton("I'm a label!");

    System.out.println(randomButton.getName()); // prints null
    System.out.println(randomButton.getText()); // prints the label
```

Also, you're comparing the label text to the button itself, you need to compare against the label:

```
// wrong
System.out.println("entered:" + source.getName());
if (source.equals("btnSave")) {

// right
System.out.println("entered:" + source.getText());
if (source.getText().equals("btnSave")) {
```

### EDIT

I missed that you weren't casting your source. Before you can run `JButton`-specific methods on your source object, you need to explicitly cast it to the correct class like so:

```
    final JButton source = (JButton) e.getComponent();
```